kid's kidnapping movie thriller
I think this is a mid-90's American movie made for TV (I think HBO aired it) where a sheriff's son/daughter gets kidnapped after a sport practice (maybe soccer). I remember that it was in winter, remember snow in the movie.
Then a woman (FBI agent/police officer) arrives in the city, she was looking for the sheriff. He was dressed in a costume for a theatrical play something like this:

During investigation they do find a tape with a recording with of the 2 kidnappers when they were younger/teenagers.
In the end I think that the kid gets returned and then the police officers realise that the should be a third suspect/kidnapper which would be the person recording the video.
That's about what I remember. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

hi,it was supposed to be something like this outfit http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDYwMA==/z/1bQAAOxyUrZS9Pkg/$_32.JPG
